# Syntax error for '&' in a remote command

Tags: bash

I want to `ssh` to a node and run a program in a background using `&`. So, the script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh NODENAME 'lmgrd -c license.lic &;
              exit;'
```

However, the bash interpreter complains for `syntax error near unexpected token ;`. It seems that `&`

Comment: Use `&` or `;`.

Comment: @Cyrus: There is one more command and for that reason I added `;`. Please see the updated post

Comment: `command1 & command2` or `command1; command2`

Comment: I removed `;` but the process doesn't run in background because `exit` is not executed.

Comment: I moved my comment to giusti‘s answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` already finisheds a command. So after `&` you simply don't use any terminator.

Comment: As I said, but the program remains in foreground. The `exit` is not executed

Comment: @mahmood: That's a second problem. Try `lmgrd -c license.lic >/dev/null &`.